# Spring Boot and Angular (5) project structure

Tags: spring, angular, maven, spring-boot, angular-cli

I have question about the best practices with these technologies in same project. What is recommended and mostly used project structure?

I saw three ways how to design project structure:

1. Create maven multi-module project, and create 2 modules (frontend with angular cli project and backend with spring project)
2. Create angular cli project into spring project on path `src/main/webapp`
3. This option is similar to second, angular cli will be also created into spring project on path `src/main/webapp` except configuration files with suffix *.json, *.ts etc ... these files will be in root within pom. So webapp folder will contains just source files and assets (jhipster style).

What do you recommend? Also when I choose one of options is it possible configure project to export angular source files into deployable JAR file? Thanks in advice.

Comment: The first way is counter intuitive. Why strongly coupling an angular project with Maven by making it a module maven ?  The second way seems the cleaner : it puts different things in different places. The third way mixes too much the two worlds too.

Comment: @davidxxx I also thinking about second or first option. First one looks the most cleaner for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been taking the approach of putting the source code where you would normally expect it - under the 'src/main' directory. So, I have src/main/java and src/main javascript, with the angular app in the latter directory.

I set up the angular app to be compiled into src/main/resources/static/ui, and configure the SpringBoot app to serve it from there.

--
Additional info - to serve the Angular app's index.html, I use this:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter forwardToIndex() {
    final String uiForward = "redirect:/ui/index.html";
    final String[] fauxRoots = new String[] {"/", "/index.html", "/ui", "/ui/"};

    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            for(String path: fauxRoots) {
                registry.addViewController(path).setViewName(uiForward);
            }
        }

    };
}
```

I have my Angular app built into src/main/resources/static/ui, and Spring will serve static content from src/main/resources/static by default (I think), so that "just works"

Comment: its nice idea :) if I use that structure, do I need classic controller for serve index file ? Or rest controller are enough, and index is served automatically ?